# Keep uniform distribution after remapping to a new range

Tags: random, probability, discrete-mathematics, prng, probability-density

Since this is about remapping a uniform distribution to another with a different range, this is not a PHP question specifically although I am using PHP.

I have a cryptographicaly secure random number generator that gives me evenly distributed integers (uniform discrete distribution) between `0` and `PHP_INT_MAX`.

How do I remap these results to fit into a different range in an efficient manner?

Currently I am using `$mappedRandomNumber = $randomNumber % ($range + 1) + $min` where `$range = $max - $min`, but that obvioulsy doesn't work since the first `PHP_INT_MAX%$range` integers from the range have a higher chance to be picked, breaking the uniformity of the distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. PRNG 101 (if it does not fit, ignore and generate again). Not very sophisticated, but simple:

```
public function rand($min = 0, $max = null){

  // pow(2,$numBits-1) calculated as (pow(2,$numBits-2)-1) + pow(2,$numBits-2) 
  // to avoid overflow when $numBits is the number of bits of PHP_INT_MAX
  $maxSafe = (int) floor(
    ((pow(2,8*$this->intByteCount-2)-1) + pow(2,8*$this->intByteCount-2))   
    / 
    ($max - $min)
  ) * ($max - $min);

  // discards anything above the last interval N * {0 .. max - min -1} 
  // that fits in {0 ..  2^(intBitCount-1)-1}
  do {
    $chars = $this->getRandomBytesString($this->intByteCount);
    $n = 0;
    for ($i=0;$i<$this->intByteCount;$i++) {$n|=(ord($chars[$i])<<(8*($this->intByteCount-$i-1)));}
  } while (abs($n)>$maxSafe);

  return (abs($n)%($max-$min+1))+$min;

}
```

Any improvements are welcomed.

(Full code on https://github.com/elcodedocle/cryptosecureprng/blob/master/CryptoSecurePRNG.php)

Answer (score 0):

Well, having zero knowledge of PHP definitely qualifies me as an expert, so

mentally converting to float U[0,1)

```
f = r / PHP_MAX_INT
```

then doing

```
mapped = min + f*(max - min)
```

going back to integers

```
mapped = min + (r * max - r * min)/PHP_MAX_INT
```

if computation is done via 64bit math, and PHP_MAX_INT being 2^31 it should work

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am afraid anything involving floats will result in trouble due to floating point representation issues and rounding errors. Also, using 64 bit math implies PHP_INT_MAX = 2^63 - 1, so there's also the overflow issue.

Comment: No, wrt float i specifically said `mentally`, final expression is all integer. Wrt `Also, using 64 bit math implies PHP_INT_MAX = 2^63 - 1, so there's also the overflow issue`, could you use 64bit math only for intermediates? Again, I have no clue about PHP, but doing only computation in braces with 64bit math and then division should work.

Comment: yeah but you can see (max-min)/PHP_INT_MAX will always be a float and there is no other way to do the calculation without overflow (doing `r * (max - min)` first will overflow in all but trivial cases)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sketch how I would do it:

Consider you have uniform random integer distribution in range `[A, B)` that's what your random number generator provide.
Let `L = B - A`.
Let `P` be the highest power of 2 such that `P <= L`.
Let `X` be a sample from this range.
First calculate `Y = X - A`.
If `Y >= P`, discard it and start with new `X` until you get an `Y` that fits.

Now `Y` contains `log2(P)` uniformly random bits - zero extend it up to `log2(P)` bits.

Now we have uniform random bit generator that can be used to provide arbitrary number of random bits as needed.

To generate a number in the target range, let `[A_t, B_t)` be the target range. Let `L_t = B_t - A_t`.
Let `P_t` be the smallest power of 2 such that `P_t >= L_t`.
Read `log2(P_t)` random bits and make an integer from it, let's call it `X_t`.
If `X_t >= L_t`, discard it and try again until you get a number that fits.
Your random number in the desired range will be `L_t + A_t`.

Implementation considerations: if your `L_t` and `L` are powers of 2, you never have to discard anything. If not, then even in the worst case you should get the right number in less than 2 trials on average.

Comment: That's smart, intuitive and effective. Also the first solution that came to my mind 4.5 years ago. If you check my code you'll see that I went one step further and removed the requirement for a log2 / random bit generator. Still not very cost effective: both solutions end up discarding up to half of the generations, but that's what remained on my production code and so far I got no performance complaints...